# The Square webhook is being triggered twice for a single event (subscription.created)

Tags: payment, subscription, square

I have registered an endpoint for the Webhook event `subscription.created` in Square. Every time I make a subscription, it triggers my webhook twice instead of once. Is there something that I missed?